# R : How to suppress a persistent warning message from alpha() function in my Rmd output?

Tags: r, warnings, alpha, suppress, psych

Program : R 3.2.1  for Mac OSX
IDE : RStudio  
Output : rmkd > html  
Package : "psych"  
Function : `alpha()`

---

Problem :   
While using `alpha(data, na.rm=F, check.keys=F, delete=F)`, because portions of the input-data is negatively correlated and because I have check.keys = FALSE, I get the following message :

> Some items XXX were negatively correlated with the total scale and
>   probably should be reversed.  To do this, run the function again with
>   the 'check.keys=TRUE' option

Question :  
 
My check.keys is set intentionally. Fully understanding the implications of the warning & mostly for aesthetic and educational reasons, how can I suppress it in my output?

Attempts so far :    
 1. I've tried `suppressWarnings()` & `suppressMessages()`. 
 
 2. I've tried `invisible()` & `sink(., type="message")`.  
 3. In the Rmd block, I've tried : ```` ```{r warning=F, message=F} ````  
 4. Exploring `print(alpha)` I found what I think is the origin. Maybe someone understands how to suppress this part of the code? :

```
`p1 <- principal(x)
if (any(p1$loadings < 0)) {
     if (check.keys) {
         warning("Some items were negatively correlated with total scale and were automatically reversed.\n This is indicated by a negative sign for the variable name.")
         keys <- 1 - 2 * (p1$loadings < 0)
         }
     else {
         warning("Some items were negatively correlated with the total scale and probably should be reversed.  To do this, run the function again with the 'check.keys=TRUE' option")
         cat("Some items (", rownames(p1$loadings)[(p1$loadings < 0)], ") were negatively correlated with the total scale and probably should be reversed.  To do this, run the function again with the 'check.keys=TRUE' option")
         }
}`
```

thanks!

Comment: This should be signalled to the developers of the code, their function does bad things (there shouldn’t be a `cat`).

Comment: Konrad is correct. Letting me know of this problem helped.  It is now fixed in psych 1.5.8  (coming to CRAN this weekend, I hope).

Comment: I did a little monkey  patch until it is hopefully fixed, see https://gist.github.com/gurix/10c675632798da04d9d2.

Answer (score 2):

The culprit here is `cat`, which will not heed `suppressMessages` etc.

To catch it, you can use [`capture.output`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/capture.output.html) instead:

```
invisible(capture.output(alpha(data, na.rm=F, check.keys=F, delete=F)))
```

`capture.output` calls `sink(…, type = "output")` internally and discards/returns the result.

Comment: thanks Konrad for your help. This does do the trick, but unfortunately doesn't suit my purposes. alpha() returns a lot of information and I'm trying to simply pull a portion of it to display in the knit file. Transforming everything into a character string using capture.output() makes my pulling less clear. Nevertheless, I learned a new trick, so thanks again. You're right that perhaps the developer of psych should modify their code.